# Return an array from a webservice to a client console

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services

I am trying to return an array of Fibonacci sequence of numbers using a webservice I wrote in c# using Visual Studio 2010. 
This is my function to create the sequence and store it in the array 'Fibon' to return to the client program.

```
 public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {
    [WebMethod]
    public long[] Fibonacci(int length) 
    {
        long[] Fibon;
        Fibon = new long [length]; 
        Fibon[0] = 0;
        Fibon[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i < length; i++)
        {
            Fibon[i] = Fibon[i - 2] + Fibon[i - 1];
        }

        return Fibon;
    }
 }`
```

The client program to call the function is as below:

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Service1 webservice = new Service1();   
        Console.Out.Write("\nHow many number of the Fibonacci sequence do you want returned?\n");
        int Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());
        long[] Sequence = new long[Number];
        Sequence = webservice.Fibonacci(Number);    // PROBLEM LINE ********
        Console.Out.Write("\nThe Sequence is \n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i <= Number; i++)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(Sequence[i]);
        }
        Console.Out.Write(",  \n\nPress ENTER to return");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'long[]"
When I run the function and test it on a browser it is working but the return to the client console is giving an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you really sure that your console application calls the `Service1.Fibonacci()` method as shown in your code example? Is your console application pointing to the correct service? If you say yes, have you proven this with debugging?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should not have error in that line, should only have problem in for loop:

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Service1 webservice = new Service1();   
        Console.Out.Write("\nHow many number of the Fibonacci sequence do you want returned?\n");
        var Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());            
        var Sequence = webservice.Fibonacci(Number);    
        Console.Out.Write("\nThe Sequence is \n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++) // Fixed LINE ********
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(Sequence[i]);
        }
        Console.Out.Write(",  \n\nPress ENTER to return");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite the loop is wrong and other weird coding elements, the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'long[]" is not been addressed by your solution. It addresses an index out of range exception.

Comment: Yes I know that, but as I said, there is no wrong with that line

Comment: I had to change the index problem and a few other lines in the code as seen in the answer below. Thank you both for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your suggestions Peyman and the solution worked. I also had to change the lines form my code

```
    int Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());                                                                                                  
    long[] Sequence = new long[Number];
    Sequence = webservice.Fibonacci(Number);
```

to the suggested lines from your code

```
    var Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());            
    var Sequence = webservice.Fibonacci(Number);
```

The code now runs and returns the sequence as required. Many Thanks!!!!!